# Need to catch an early morning taxi from central Paris to CDG airport!

Tags: airport-transfer, hotels, paris, taxis, cdg

I need to catch an early morning international flight at 08:00 am from Paris CDG, so I need a taxi at around  05:00 am to get from my hotel which is located at central Paris close to Arc de Triomphe.

I am just a tourist and will stay 4 days in Paris. Since I am choosing a cheap hotel, I'm a bit afraid they won't help me to book a taxi.

Will they help me or not? If not how to book a taxi in paris, any app recommendation?
If the flight departure time at 08:00 am, is it enough time if I book the taxi at 05:00 am?

Comment: Have you asked them if they can call a cab for you ? Is your flight international ? There's always the option of taking the metro, I just checked and it seems the RER is open at 5:20am

Comment: Why wouldn't they help you?

Comment: International flight as mentioned in the question. I have not been in paris before so I dont know if its standard that hotel staf help one to book a taxi or not, therfore I asked you here to have plan B in case they will not help

Comment: Can you provide me with the official website of RER, where did you find 05:20 ?

Comment: They probably will call you a taxi, or a non-taxi car, because they will probably get a small fee for everyone they refer. In any case, asking them is the thing to do.

Comment: Note that getting taxi from central(ish) Paris to CDG is pretty seriously expensive - like €90 or similar I seem to recall. If the train (RER) is running, then it will be much cheaper. Public transport in Paris is run by RATP - their website is http://www.ratp.fr/

Comment: Enjoy Paris!  Note that (a) there is a STAGGERING amount of traffic at that time of the morning.  (b) it is 99.99% certain the hotel will be extremely helpful about getting you a taxi - there is absolutely no problem there, you can count on it.  (c) taxis are quite expensive - BUT if you take public transport you still have to pay for the "local taxi" which is tricky; sometimes it's worth "sucking it up" and just accepting you have to pay for a taxi to the airport; it is INCREDIBLY nicer than the depressing public transport to the airport.  BUT be aware of the traffic.

Comment: Since nobody else has addressed your actual question **"If the flight departure time at 08:00 am, is it enough time if I book the taxi at 05:00 am?"** I urge you to simply email the hotel - all French hotels  like email these days - or perhaps phone them, and ASK.  they will decisively tell you.  Please report back here.

Comment: BTW you should simply state the name of the hotel?  (There's no security risk or downside to that.)  It will help locals know exactly how long it takes.

Comment: @PLS I will offer you one of those "it's too late now" tips.  A fantastic suggestion when staying in Paris for only a few days.  It sounds like you got a great hotel; you should have booked that hotel *but only for the first 3 nights*.  For ***the final night only*** book the absolutely fantastic and bargain price **IBIS** at CDG.  So on your final day you check out of your hotel at a relaxed time, and of course they will store your bags. Have another fantastic day in Paris and have a relaxed dinner. In the evening, simply take your time to easily (and cheaply) make your way to the airport...

Comment: ...walk the pleasant couple hundred meters to the IBIS and sleep incredibly soundly all night knowing what a smart travel decision you have made. In the morning, you feel like a billionaire because you can sleep in comfortably and get up at your leisure and literally stroll to the aircraft!!!  This is a HUGE travel tip for Paris, when you have a ridiculously early morning flight as you have.  I feel bad I could not have offered this tip earlier!  :)  if it's not "too late" you should change your travel arrangements like this!

Comment: (If you are rich, do this but choose the wonderous Sheraton hotel which is built right in to CDG airport - it's perhaps the world's most convenient airport hotel, it's totally awesome.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to get to the Roissy (CDG) airport from the Arc de Triomphe (usually called “Place de l'Étoile” or just “Étoile” by the locals, and sometimes known as “Charles de Gaulle” on transport maps — not to be confused with “Charles de Gaulle” refering to the airport!).

[Air France runs coaches](http://en.lescarsairfrance.com/) to the airport, and one of the lines goes from Étoile to CDG. That's by far the simplest way for you, but they might not start early enough. They're more expensive than the train or even than a night bus plus train, but a lot cheaper than a taxi. The [first bus](http://www.lescarsairfrance.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/l2_horaires2.pdf) departs at 5:45 and the journey should take a little under 1 hour.

[RATP](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61852/roissybus/) (the local public transport company) also runs buses to CDG. The buses are only slightly more expensive than the train. The downside of RATP buses is that they leave from place de l'Opéra, a little over 3km away from Étoile. The upside is that the first bus leaves Opéra at 5:15; the journey takes about 1 hour.

[RER B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RER_B) is a commuter train that runs through the center of the city and has a branch that terminates at CDG. You can find the full schedule on the [RATP website](http://www.ratp.fr/horaires/fr/ratp/rer) (pick direction “Charles-de-Gaulle”, and “[lundi à vendredi](http://www.ratp.fr/informer/pdf/orienter/f_horaire.php?nompdf=b_jo_cdg&loc=horaires)” for weekdays or “[samedi, dimanche et jours fériés](http://www.ratp.fr/informer/pdf/orienter/f_horaire.php?nompdf=b_sd_cdg&loc=horaires)” for week-ends and [public holidays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_France)). The first train arrives at the airport at 5:31. It departs from Gare du Nord at 4:53 (from the upper-level platforms, unlike later trains which go through the underground platforms). The first train from the central station Châtelet-Les-Halles departs at 5:26 and arrives at 6:05, after this there are trains every 8 minutes or better.

From Étoile, the most direct way to catch line B is to take RER line A to Châtelet-Les-Halles. You'll need to change platforms at Châtelet-Les-Halles: lines A and B share a platform but that would be the train in the wrong direction. The first train from Étoile leaves at 5:13 and arrives at Châtelet-Les-Halles at 5:19. Note that from 27 July to 07 August 2015, traffic on line A will be suspended around Étoile, so if you're traveling during this period, you'll need to take a bus to Auber then change for a train; these deviations are usually well sign-posted, but they add considerably to the journey time.

If RER B is fine but RER A isn't, you may want to take a taxi to Gare du Nord. It'll be a lot cheaper than going all the way to the airport, but somewhat slower.

Paris has a [night bus](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/c_20564/voyager-la-nuit/) [network](http://www.ratp.fr/informer/pdf/orienter/f_plan.php?fm=pdf&loc=reseaux&nompdf=noctilien). You can use an ordinary ticket (“ticket t+”) for a trip inside Paris. If you go all the way to the airport, you'll need to stamp 4 tickets. If you change buses, you need to stamp a new ticket. Many lines are infrequent, so do check the schedule in advance and arrive at the stop early. Stops are clearly marked with the “N” logo but make sure you know where exactly to find your bus as Place de l'Étoile is very large.

- From Étoile to Gare du Nord, there is no direct bus. Check the [schedule planner](http://www.ratp.fr/itineraires/en/ratp/recherche-avancee) to see the possibilities.
- If you want a lift towards Opéra, take N53 to Saint-Lazare and walk about 1km.
- On the other hand, Châtelet-Les-Halles is easy to reach, because it's next to the center point of the night bus network. Take N11 or N24 and get off at Châtelet.
- Line N143 to Roissy airport leaves Gare de l'Est (only a few blocks away from Gare du Nord). If the earliest RER B is too late for you, [N143](http://www.ratp.fr/informer/pdf/orienter/f_horaire.php?nompdf=n143&loc=noctilien) can get you there earlier; it runs every half hour and the journey time is an hour or less depending on which terminal you're going to.

If you decide to take a taxi for all or part of the journey, there are companies that let you book online. If you're going to pay by credit card, make sure to take a booking that guarantees the possibility — some taxi drivers can't or won't take cards. The price for the trip to Gare du Nord should be around 15€, to the airport might be something like 60€. Alternatively, you might want to book a car-with-a-driver-that-isn't-a-taxi (“VTC”), which offers a pre-arranged fare and almost always accepts payment cards. Unlike taxis, VTC fares are not regulated, and may end up being more or less expensive than a taxi.

Comment: I think RER A "which departs from Étoile at 5:13 and arrives at Châtelet-Les-Halles at 5:19" will be fine and will arrive in good time

Comment: this is fantastic information about the public transport option